# Trying to save PDF form fields using iText (PdfAction.createSubmitForm). Losing existing javascript on jsp

Tags: java, pdf-generation, adobe, itext

I am trying to create a pdf where user fills the fields and saves the data. I created a 'save' button on pdf using iText. I am settig the action of the button using PdfAction.createSubmitForm. While I am getting the formfield values of pdf while saving, I am losing the existing javascript on my JSP due to this button.  I am using PdfAction.SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT in the save button. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. You have a PDF containing AcroForm fields. You post the key/value pairs of these fields to the server the same way you would submit an HTML querystring. So far, so good. However: "losing the existing javascript on my JSP" doesn't make sense. There is no JSP on the client side, only a PDF document.  You aren't sending any JSP to the server, only something like *key1=value1&key2=value2&...* Somebody who is unaware of your application has no idea why you are talking about JSP and how Javascript is related to the Java in your JSP.

Comment: In our application, we are trying to display a JSP right after user hits the Save button on the PDF. The jsp which is being displayed has its header breaking, as its not receiving some toolbar of our framework. Actually now its been resolved as I am redirecting the servlet action once the save button is hit.

Comment: Lowagie, I might not be able to express my scenarion clearly, but I posted my answer below. Please let me know if you need further clarification, as it might be helpful if you incorporate this into your iText book.

Comment: Your answer solves your problem, but it would never make my book because you've implemented a `sendRedirect` that is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. If I redirect the servlet action, the JSP displayed is then working fine.

Below is the code

```
HttpServletResponse response ;
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setContentLength(13);

            String url = new URL(request.getScheme(),request.getServerName(), request.getServerPort(),request.getRequestURI()).toExternalForm();

            String target = url+"?action="ServletAction";

            response.addHeader("Refresh", new StringBuilder(target.length() + 5)
                .append("0;url=").append(target).toString());

            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.print("<html></html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read your answer and although it solves your problem (and clarifies the initial problem), you are solving the problem in a really bad way. You are sending an almost empty HTML file `<html></html>` to the browser and you're expecting that the browser will respect the `Refresh` header. This is *so unprofessional*!

Redirecting is done like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    String url = new URL(request.getScheme(),request.getServerName(), request.getServerPort(),request.getRequestURI()).toExternalForm();
    String target = url+"?action=ServletAction";
    response.sendRedirect(target);
}
```

Replace `doGet` with `doPost` if your code snippet was part of a `doPost` method.

Comment: I tried redirecting, but then the JSP header is breaking with that approach.